# Phone downloads mysterious file

Tags: updates, hardware

I wasn't doing anything with my phone, when I pulled it out of my pocket a notification saying "-tWW3IHZgSg - Download complete." was visible. This file was in the downloads folder, I copied it to my PC and running the unix "file" command on it returned "Macromedia Flash data (compressed), version 17". I certainly didn't download it and I have no idea what it could be. Here is a DropBox link of the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yowi4qlnlxuf6wz/-tWW3IHZgSg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a flash animation file. Without access to my computer, I can't find out for certain.

As for why it showed up in your downloads? Most likely an error in a program that caused a download notification when downloading cache data or a temporary file, judging by the filename. Probably an advert or small animation from a webpage or app. 
It's worth noting that most free apps have ads as well as most websites, and most advert animations are flash animations.

TL;DR: Probably a glitch causing an advert or cached page animation to appear in your downloads.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but viruses/trojans sometimes also have such filenames so it kinda scared me.

Comment: @0ne_Up What phone are you using, and what version of Android are you running? Also, it's your device rooted?

Comment: Samsumg Galaxy S5 mini (SM-G800F), Android 4.4.2. Yes it's rooted.

Comment: @0ne_Up Sure you haven't downloaded any suspicious apps recently? Also, in my experience, Android versions that sit around 4.x.x are a little glitchy sometimes.

Comment: I didn't download any apps recently